# problema ya sea con print(f"ejemplo{variable}") o el input con el f-strigns

Tags: python

'''print(f'{num1} {symbols} {num2} = {primera_respuesta}')'''

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: quiza estás usando una versión de python anterior a la 3.6

Comment: No dice cuál es el problema ni qué pretende hacer

Answer (score 0):

Como queres que sea tu output?

```
prueba = 1
variable = input(f'Esto es una prueba: {prueba}.... aca escribis tu valor para variable:  ')
print(variable)
```

Tu output es el valor que le des a variable.

Si queres que variable contenga 2 valores crea una lista.

```
prueba = 1
variable = [(input(f'Esto es una prueba: .... aca escribis tu valor para variable:  ')), prueba]
print(variable)
```

Comment: lo que quiero es que me deje meter el input junto con la variable en la terminal pero no se por que me sale el error segun yo esta bien la syntax por que tenia archivos que sin funcionaban similares y ya no funcionan

Comment: @sergioronquillo si lees los comentarios, alguien dice que podrías estar usando una versión anterior a la 3.6. Es decir, antes de que los f-strings existan. De ahí el syntax error. La solución es NO usar f-strings o actualizar Python a 3.6 o superior.

Comment: estoy usando python 3.10.6

Comment: Proba como el primer ejemplo que te pase

Comment: ya no funciono el problema es el f-string parece como si fuera una version vieja de python pero ya desistale y volvia instalar